# Drawbacks of extending Magento guest session maxlifetime?

Tags: php, session, magento

We are interested in extending the session duration for guests that visit our Magento website. By default if a guest adds an item to the cart and leaves the page afer 24 minutes the session is destroyed and when they return the cart is zeroed. I extended the maxlifetime via htaccess to 6 hours to test it out and it works correctly. I know my manager is interested in keeping sessions alive for 1 week or even longer. My question is: what are the potential drawbacks of keeping sessions alive this long? Server performance, server space for session files, security concerns, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have explicit PCI compliance directives to only retain session data for a specific window - there isn't any real security concerns. The session data doesn't hold any sensitive information.

**By extending the window, the only concerns I can think about would be.**

1. You are giving a longer/greater chance for the session/customer to be vulnerable to an XSS attack on the existing session (not that this wouldn't perhaps otherwise be the case anyway).
2. You run the risk of the session directory becoming excessively large - causing any session clean-up cron's to have to iterate through an increased number of files.
3. If you are storing anything else in the session that you shouldn't be doing (ie. that makes it larger than the default 4kb); then you'll be rapidly consuming disk space.
4. If you are using memory storage for sessions (Memcache/Redis) - then you'll eventually run out of available space and auto-truncate older sessions. So you'll have to commit a fairly large amount of RAM purely for legacy/archived session storage.
5. If you are using DB storage for the sessions - then you'll end up in a bad way. Magento's DB based session storage is horrendous and falls over at the slightest hint of use - ***avoid***
6. A potential security concern could perhaps be if the customer's machine is a shared computer. At least with a 24 minute (or otherwise) session volatility, chances are the session would have expired before another user can take advantage of it.

#### But there is a better solution

Rather than just extend session time on site, have you perhaps thought of investigating a more sophisticated solution, whereby if the cart has been abandoned, you can alert the customer of such via email and give them a link to re-instate the cart contents/wishlist/session etc.

This would obviously give you the underlying solution and the advantage that you could pro-actively convert the customer - and all it would require is capture of an email address.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed write up. We are working on our abandoned cart re-marketing but it doesnt address people who dont have an account with us. We get a lot of people that come first time from a PPC ad or something, add a few items into their cart, and leave the website. Sometimes they call back later in the day saying they went to complete their order and the cart was empty. We cater to an older demographic so we are trying to keep it as painless as possible.

Comment: Ah understood. An interesting challenge if you don't want to interrupt the users on-site experience; and the older market is unlikely going to benefit from 1-Click auth via Twitter/FB/Google. Out of interest, does this site cater to the EU - as you might fall victim to the infamous cookie law; and they'll almost definitely be some particulars in there about session expiry (jeopardising your project even further).

Comment: US based with no international dealings so will be ok for now.